# Expected Declaration Specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm a beginner in C, i just have 13 years, so i'm pretty sure that the error is something very basic.

I was bored in school, i started writing C about a "Game".

Here is it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int * id;
    int * posx;
    int * posy;
    char * name;
} entity;

int allocData(&entity) {
    entity->id = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(entity->id == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    entity->posx = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(entity->posx == NULL) {
        return ;
    }
    entity->posy = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(entity->posy = NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    entity->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 129);
    if(entity->name == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    entity player;
    allocData(&player);
    player.id = 0;
    player.name = "loopback\0";
    printf("ID: %d, Name: %s", player.id, player.name);
    return 0;
}
```

But GCC complains.

```
main.c:11:15: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 int allocData(&entity) {
               ^
```

I can't find the error, and i didn't want to post here, i'm sure is something stupid that i missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function definition should take pointer as an argument:

```
int allocData(entity *player);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your prototype looks wrong:

> int allocData(&entity)  // <-- what is the type? and why it's address operator here??

It should be:

```
int allocData(entity * p_entity)
```

You should also replace all your `entity` variable name in function `allocData` - remember `entity` is your **type** name, not variable.

Comment: The code [compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0oDJsjBWluj082Ke) even when the type name and variable name are the same.

Comment: I think using variable name that differ from type name is good because it is less confusing.

Comment: @MikeCAT definitely should use a different name

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use reference in C.

In this case, you should want to use a pointer.

change the line`int allocData(&entity) {` to `int allocData(entity *entity) {`, and the code will compile.

Although this change will make the code compile, you will invoke *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: `%d` expects for `int`, but you passed `int*`. You will also cause memory leak by throwing away the pointer assinged in `allocData()`.  I don't think using pointer unless they are needed isn't good.

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* add this for using strcpy() */

typedef struct {
    int id;
    int posx;
    int posy;
    char name[129];
} entity;

/* now allocData() won't be needed because entity doesn't have any member to allocate pointer to */

int main(void) {
    entity player;
    player.id = 0;
    /* use strcpy() to copy strings */
    /* \0 here will be meaningless in this case, so I removed this */
    strcpy(player.name, "loopback");
    printf("ID: %d, Name: %s", player.id, player.name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!